# Installed pyglet module not found

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pyglet

I tried to install pyglet module by writing pip install pyglet to my command prompt. It obviously worked because it says:

```
Installing collected packages: pyglet
Successfully installed pyglet-1.4.1
```

However, when I write `import pyglet` at the beginning of my python code and try to run the program, it says:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyglet'
```

Then I wrote `python -m pyglet.info` to my cmd and it says: `sys.platform: win32` and `pyglet.compat_platform: win32`. Does this mean that this pyglet module is made for 32bit windows? Note that my python is 32-bit, but my windows is 64-bit. Do I have to install 64-bit pyglet and if I do, how do I do it?

Comment: Yes and no, `pyglet.compat_platform: win32` doesn't mean it'll only work on 32bit windows per se. It means it'll run on a 32bit Python instance that'll only run under a 32bit execution environment. 64bit windows will however manage running 32bit applications just fine at the time of writing this. How are you executing your script? through an IDE or from command line? Do you have both Python2 and Python3 installed? What happens if you open a cmd and start python and write `import pyglet`?

Comment: @Torxed I have the same problem. I am not using IDE.  I am using Python 3.9.11 at command prompt (that is, cmd). conda install pyglet fails.